How do you store inputs from users on your app and keep them displaying on Bubble.io
Hi I am making an app that has some user input. It is a health tracking app and I want the inputs to be stored even if the user shutsdown the app. For example, if the user drinks a bit of water the user puts that in the app that increases the amount of water displayed by increments of 100 but as soon as i close the app that data is gone. I made it that the data is stored at the end of the day but if the data is gone before that i cant store anything. Is there a way to keep the data displaying and keep it saved temporarily for the day in real-time and then actually store the data in a database at the end of the day? Thanks in advance!
